# Merging cells within a column if the same data is in the cells

Tags: google-sheets

On google docs spreadsheet is there anyway to put in some sort of formulae/ script which will merge cells in the same column in to another.

For example, making all the apples merge so it's on one row?

```
Apple   2   3   4   5
APPLE   2   3   4   5
APPLE   2   3   4   5
Banana  2   3   4   5
Peanuts 2   3   4   5
Banana  2   3   4   5
Cheese  2   3   4   5
Apple   2   3   4   5
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

`=UNIQUE(A:E)`

Note: "APPLE" and "Apple" are different values. A workaround is to make all values same case:

`=ArrayFormula(UNIQUE(LOWER(A:E)))`

To have the unique list only by column A and return the other columns next to it:

`=QUERY(
  ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(LOWER(A:A)),A:E,{1,2,3,4,5},)),
 "limit "&COUNTUNIQUE(A:A)-1)`

Comment: If the the cells in the other columns do not match, is there anyway to still merge, for example, if column c had different inputs but still wanted it to merge. Just focus on the one column but merge any information from the other columns in to the same row?

Comment: What if Column b, c, d, e, had different information in them for example.

A would be numbers that we would want to merge together so like a photo number.

The B, C, D, E would be for different queries/ written messages received. 
So it would all be different inputs on the rows. Anyway of merging them into one row?

Comment: Please, provide an example of merging. I suppose that when you have codes 1 in a row, and 2 in another row, merging them is a new string: "1, 2". If so, the formula may be way harder. Please, add another question with more details of the desired result to get answers from SO community.